# Get Android Volley response in another class

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley

I'm trying to use Volley as a DBA layer to call a webservice that hadles JSON objects. Because this layer is below the activity and another service layer, it doesn't seem to be working properly. I'll try to explain my setup:

MainActivity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ProductService productService = new ProductService();
    productService.getProduct();
}
```

ProductService.java:

```
    public void getProduct() {
            JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest("http://echo.jsontest.com/name/Milk/price/1.23/", null, createMyReqSuccessListener(), createMyReqErrorListener());
            ApplicationController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req);
        }

        private Response.Listener<JSONObject> createMyReqSuccessListener() {
            return new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.v("response", response.toString());
                }
            };
        }

        private Response.ErrorListener createMyReqErrorListener() {
            return new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                   return;
                }
            };
        }
```

I hope that is clear enough.
In the end, I would like to use the ProductService::getProduct() from an activity and the the actual JSON response from the webservice in a variable which I can later use.

However, at the moment, the line

```
Log.v("response", response.toString());
```

doesn't even execute. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you getting an Error response instead? You've got no `Log` in there, so you may not notice.

Comment: There is no error message. The code is just not executed. My feeling is that because of this class workflow, that listener is not found and executed. I would really want to know what happens when I do queue.add(req) in Volley.

Comment: I copied your code almost verbatim and it worked for me first time. [Source](https://gist.github.com/adamsp/6bdc3bcc1c663e63b14d). The only thing I can see would be either you're not adding requests to your queue correctly, or you're missing Internet permission in your manifest.

Comment: There is a very big difference between my code and yours: mine is spread in two classes and yours is all in the main activity. I think that's actually the problem with my code: the MainActivity delegates functionality to another class, and because of this delegation, the Response.Listener is not being called.

Comment: But for me, that's the whole point. I want to keep my MainActivity code clean and separated from the DBA layer.

Comment: You need to post your code for setting up your Volley request queue then - `ApplicationController` here, it appears. Being in 2 different classes  is irrelevant, as the queue is a singleton anyway and that's the only common piece.

Comment: The question is, as I see it, that after the queue executes, it passes back control to the activity instead of any other object that might be the Listener or ErrorListener.

Comment: Well, yeah, that's how asynchronous operations work. Post your code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46040/discussion-between-zorrocaesar-and-adam-s)

Answer (score 3):

What I would try is this:

Declare getProduct as

```
public void getProduct(Response.Listener<JSONObject> listener, 
                       Response.ErrorListener errlsn) {
            JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest("http://echo.jsontest.com/name/Milk/price/1.23/",null, listener, errlsn);
            ApplicationController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req);
        }
```

And than call in your activity like this:

```
productService.getProduct(
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                       variableFromActivity = response;
                       //Or call a function from the activity, or whatever...
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                       //Show error or whatever...
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an abstract class AppActivity

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public abstract class AppActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    abstract void callback(String data);
}
```

Extend all your Activities using AppActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppActivity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String url = "Your URL";

        JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject();
        try {
            jsonBody.put("Title", "Android Volley Demo");
            jsonBody.put("Author", "BNK");
        }
        catch (JSONException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        final String requestBody = jsonBody.toString();

        Messenger messenger = new Messenger(MainActivity.this);
        messenger.sendMessage(this, url, requestBody);

    }

    public void callback(String data)
    {
        System.out.println(data);
    }
}
```

Create Messenger class as below:

```
public class Messenger
{
    private AppActivity myActivity;

    public  Messenger(AppActivity activity)
    {
        myActivity = activity;
    }

    public void sendMessage(Context context, String url, final String requestBody)
    {
        // Instantiate the RequestQueue.
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);

        // Request a string response from the provided URL.
        StringRequest stringRequest =
                new StringRequest(
                        Request.Method.POST,
                        url,
                        null,
                        new Response.ErrorListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                System.out.println(error);
                            }
                        }
                ) {
                    @Override
                    public String getBodyContentType() {
                        return "application/json; charset=utf-8";
                    }

                    @Override
                    public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
                        try {
                            return requestBody == null ? null : requestBody.getBytes("utf-8");
                        }
                        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
                            VolleyLog.wtf("Unsupported Encoding while trying to get the bytes of %s using %s", requestBody, "utf-8");
                            return null;
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response)
                    {
                        myActivity.callback(new String(response.data));

                        String responseString = "";
                        if (response != null) {
                            responseString = String.valueOf(response.statusCode);
                            // can get more details such as response.headers
                        }
                        return Response.success(responseString, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
                    }
                };

        queue.add(stringRequest);
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.